# Android: Opaque card.io view on all Samsung devices

Tags: card.io

I have integrated card.io in my Android application and when I send an intent to invoke card.io activity, it opens up the camera view with card.io view totally opaque and I do not see the credit card in the view. This behavior is only seen on Samsung devices and not on other OEM devices. I see a grey colored rectangle instead of the card.io view and native camera view around this rectangle.

Surprisingly, sample card.io application also behaves the same view.

Could you please look into this issue and provide details on how to fix this issue? Is this a known issue?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Which version of card.io, and what devices?  Card.io has had no problems on any Samsung devices that I'm aware of.

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.1.5 and I see the issue on all the samsung devices. The same behavior is seen on the sample card.io application. On all other devices, view is not opaque and credit card is visible in the view.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem.  I saw you posted it in the issues here: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/21 so it looks like you were able to resolve it by adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the action.  I had to put it at the application level and it worked for me.

Comment: I've added this change to the SampleApp: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/AndroidManifest.xml#L22

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Note 3 and Note 4 devices until I removed 
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
from my manifest.