# card.io does not recognise card on Galaxy S5

Tags: android, card.io

card.io SDK for android integrated in my app works on different devices but on Galaxy S5 it does not come to "snap" after focusing around the camera. I know S5 has quite a different CPU and GPU and some different camera properties. Anyone having the same experience?

Comment: I see some odd artifacts on my Galaxy S5 running 4.2.2, so it looks like there could be some bugs. We'll look into it. Can you share the version of Android you're running?

Comment: Digging a little further, I came across the discussion about other Samsung devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792440/android-opaque-card-io-view-on-all-samsung-devices

Comment: Now that I added hardware acceleration as described, I see normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to comment from tomwhipple above: just adding "android:hardwareAccelerated="false"" does the trick.